# How can I save a Image in my Photos in iOS

Tags: image, swift, uiview, imageview, assetslibrary

I want to get an image from a UIView, when users , taps the save button, and then the image should be save in the photos album 
How Can I Do that , is there any Method in UIImage or CGImage , that allow us to load an image from a UIView ?

Comment: Have you looked at the [`UIImage` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIImage). I see something about your question in the fourth paragraph.

Comment: yes , but i can't load the image from a UIView

Comment: what do you mean when you say "image from a UIView"?

Comment: i mean , i'm making  drawing App
there is the drawView : UIView, and i want the user to be able to save his draw in his photo Album